# How do I upgrade from Skyrim to Skyrim Anthology without losing saves, characters, and mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've played many hours and developed a character and saves with a regular Skyrim disk on XP PC. I have just received The Elder Scrolls Anthology for Christmas! How do I install Skyrim Legendary without losing my character saves / progress in the "regular" game. I am using a handful of mods as well.

Can anyone point me to a step by step guide to upgrading to Legendary without loss of my previous effort or provide directions?

Comment: They are the same program, so long as you do not remove your My Games folder, you won't lose data.

Answer (score 2):

Skyrim stores savegames inside `My Documents\My Games\Skyrim`, so you don't have to worry about losing saves. You will need to configure your mod manager to use the new directory and reinstall your mods if you want to keep using them, though.